# Is nvidia-docker "outdated"? Are there cases where a *new* project would still rely on nvidia-docker?

Tags: docker

Is [nvidia-docker](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker) "outdated"? Latest release at the time of writing is September 2020. I guess that only docker is used nowadays, and not nvidia-docker? Or are there still cases where a *new* project would still rely on nvidia-docker?

Background:

I am asking this because I tried to solve some errors with a missing `X server` using a guide of nvidia-docker, and I tried [rViz in nvidia-docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59388345/rviz-in-nvidia-docker-container) to get rid of an `OGRE EXCEPTION(3:RenderingAPIException)` error, not knowing about the difference between docker and nvidia-docker. I chose nvidia-docker just because I have an nvidia graphics card, thus it seemed to fit at first sight. Then a fellow told me that this is "old stuff", although from the date of the guides and threads found, you would not have thought it would be outdated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is.

As of Docker release 19.03, NVIDIA GPUs are natively supported as devices in the
Docker runtime, so `nvidia-docker2` is deprecated.

For more information see the article
[Workstation Setup for Docker with the New NVIDIA Container Toolkit (nvidia-docker2 is deprecated)](https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/hpc/Workstation-Setup-for-Docker-with-the-New-NVIDIA-Container-Toolkit-nvidia-docker2-is-deprecated-1568/).